# How to avoid unwanted updating of files while merging in TortoiseHG?

Tags: merge, mercurial

These files should not have been updated. How can i tell TortoiseHG so?

[image]

Comment: Did you have the "Force merge with outstanding changes" option selected when you started the Merge?

Comment: where this option should occure?

Comment: ( FYI I didn't see your comment because you didn't use the @DaveInCaz in the message - you should do that :)  )

Comment: When you do Repository menu > Merge from Tortoise HG Workbench, you get a checkbox option for the 'Force..." thing I mentioned